# Performance AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, performance

I create a Logs with tabel. What options are a better way to increase performance?

1. I extract all rows from Database and I filter them from AngularJS.
2. When an user type a new filter, I send a HTTP request and I select from database.

I wanna do the first option but I think will lagging because I will have maybe 50.000 rows?

Answer (score 1):

Selecting from a database is **much** faster.

Databases are designed for super fast querying of data, angular filters are somewhat fast, but are no where as good as a database (which are designed to do super-fast queries super-quickl)

Oh! And if you have 50000 rows, each with around 200 bytes of data, you'll be using 10 megabytes of data per load - that's **huge**, and browsers (especially mobile) don't handle large logic operations well.

So use database **whenever** you can, and only use angular filters when you **already** have data client-side.